# My ext4 disk is bigger on the outside

Tags: 16.04, ext4, hybrid-efi

Successfully installed a clean 16.04 onto a Hybrid Disk (Seagate® Laptop Thin SSHD) on an HP Laptop that previously refused to run without Windows.

All Ubuntu tools, gparted, disks, nautilus tell me there are ~7Gb of space used but when I try to backup the partition with a Free Macrium Reflect Recovery USB it tells me its ~27Gb.

I have tried older versions of Macrium and all say the same, with the prior Ubuntu 14.04 (ext3) on a NON hybrid drive this was not an issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this "Bigger on the Outside" issue?

Answer (score 1):

Each partition has a part reserved for root. This makes a part of the drive unavailable to normal users. It is usually 5%, which often means many gigabytes, far more than sudo would ever need. You can change it to less than 5% (or even 0) with the *tune2fs* program.

Comment: Makes sense, I started with a 100Gb (5%=20) partition which I shrank to 85Gb. However setting Reserved to 0 changed the Reserved Blocks but did not change the result via Reflect.